# Change last clicked button properties c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button

In my form i have about 36 buttons and for each i have the following code

```
        button3.BackColor = Color.DarkGreen;
        button_click("A1");
        button3.Enabled = false;
        nr_l++;
        textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(nr_l);
```

which means I will have this code x 36 times, I want to make a method that does this but I dont know how  to change last clicked buttons properties, i want something like this :

```
    private void change_properties()
    {
    last_clicked_button.backcolor = color.darkgreen;
    button_click("A3"); //this is a method for adding A3 to a string,   
    last_clicked_button.enabled = false;
    nr_l++;
    textbox4.text = convert.tostring(nr_l);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    change_properties();
    }
```

How can i tell change_properties method that it should work with button3 in case it was clicked?

Comment: The `sender` variable has this information. For example: `Button curButton = (Button)sender; if(curButton.Name == "button3"){//this is button3}`. You can associate the same method (e.g., `private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){}`) to the click events of all the buttons and recognise the given button in this way. At least, this is the answer to what seems to be your last question, because your whole post is quite unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the button as a parameter to the method -

```
change_properties(Button lastClickedButton)
```

And then use this parameter to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If what you do with your 36 buttons are identical, then for each of your `Button.Click` `events` (likely declared in your designer.cs file), refers it to a single `event handler`

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click); //notice the event name is the same
....
this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click); //notice the event name is the same
....
this.button36.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click); //notice the event name is the same
```

And then in your event handler, convert the `sender` object to `Button` class by using `as Button`

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button; //button is your last clicked button
    //do whatever you want with your button. This is necessarily the last clicked
}
```

If it is not, then just leave the declarations of the event handler but make the `button` as the input for your `change_properties` method

```
private void change_properties(Button button)
{
    button.backcolor = color.darkgreen;
    button_click("A3"); //this is a method for adding A3 to a string,   
    button.enabled = false;
    nr_l++;
    textbox4.text = convert.tostring(nr_l);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //the name of the event handler is unique per `Button` Control
{
    change_properties(sender as Button);
    //do something else specific for button1
}

....

private void button36_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    change_properties(sender as Button);
    //do something else specific for button36
}
```